# Need insight with grading in C using switch, and case tags

Tags: c

```
printf("On a scale of (A - F) rate your experience with our Consortium's HR Department\n\n");
char Grading;
    printf("\nEnter a grade: \n\n");
    scanf("%c", &rate);

    switch (Grading) {
    case 'A':
        printf("Perfect!\n\n");
        break;
        case 'B':
        printf("You did good!\n\n");
        break;
    case 'C':
        printf("You did okay\n\n");
        break;
    case 'D':
        printf("At least not bad\n\n");
        break;
    case 'E':
        printf("Bad\n\n");
        break;
    case 'F':
        printf("Awful\n\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Please enter only valid grades\n\n");
        
}
return 0;
}
```

This is just the section i need help with in my codeblocks. Doing this separately on a different visual studio tab works, but together with my previous codes;it keeps saying enter only valid grades

I tried making a grading on C. My code actually works, i mean that exact grading code block works on a different tab. But when added to my previous code, the project ima working on, it keeps saying enter only valid grades. Ima kinda asking if there's a finna conventional method of adding the C grading block to a project in C

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve] including input along with expected output vs. actual output. Also read this: [ask].

Comment: Or maybe it's just a typo: `scanf("%c", &rate);` -> `scanf("%c", &Grading);` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your switch statement you are checking the value of `Grading`, but `scanf` writes its output in `rate`.

You should change your switch case like so:

```
printf("On a scale of (A - F) rate your experience with our Consortium's HR Department\n\n");
char rate; //rename Grading to rate
    printf("\nEnter a grade: \n\n");
    scanf("%c", &rate);

    switch (rate) { //rename Grading to rate
    case 'A':
        printf("Perfect!\n\n");
        break;
        case 'B':
        printf("You did good!\n\n");
        break;
    case 'C':
        printf("You did okay\n\n");
        break;
    case 'D':
        printf("At least not bad\n\n");
        break;
    case 'E':
        printf("Bad\n\n");
        break;
    case 'F':
        printf("Awful\n\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Please enter only valid grades\n\n");
        
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&Grading` instead of `&rate`

Or

Declare `char rate` instead of `Grading`

You have declared `Grading` and `scanf` uses `rate`